# Linq Groupby Not Grouping in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, vue.js, entity

Below i have a snippet of code which outputs a list of Appointments based on clients, some clients can have more than one appointment but the latest one is the one that needs to be outputted for said client

the output is not grouping at all and for some reason i cannot figure why the heck not

```
foreach (ClientRecord client in clients)
                {
                    List<ReturnRecord> records = db.Appointments
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Include(rec => rec.Property)
                        .Include(rec => rec.Property.Address)
                        .Include(rec => rec.AppointmentType)
                        .ToList()
                        .Where(rec => rec.ClientID == client.ID)
                        .Select(rec => new ReturnRecord
                        {
                            ClientName = $"{client.FirstNames} {client.Surnames}",
                            PropertyAddress = $"{rec.Property.Address.FormattedAddress}",
                            AppStatus = $"{rec.AppointmentStatus.Name}",
                            StockStatus = $"{rec.Property.Stocks.FirstOrDefault().StockStatus.Name}",
                            LastUpdated = rec.LastUpdated
    
                        })
                        .ToList();
    
                    returnList.AddRange(records);
    
                }
                returnList.GroupBy(rec => rec.PropertyAddress);
    
                return Ok(returnList);
```

here is an attachment of the screen grab of the output
[image]

Comment: the `GroupBy` method has a return value! it is not void. You need to catch the returnvalue. It will not simply modify your source collection on which you call the method. [Here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) please read this.

Comment: `GroupBy` (as basically all LINQ methods is not an action, but function returning result which you are discarding (not using).

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign result of GroupBy() to variable:

```
returnList = returnList.GroupBy(rec => rec.PropertyAddress).ToList();
```

Comment: how can answer with uncompileable code get 3 upvotes? Please edit your post, and write the correct return type. Make your code at least compileable

Comment: I downvoted because this answer is partly wrong and does not compile

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to actually use the new IEnumerable that the `.GroupBy()` Method returned.

If you want to return a List you need to use a workaround:

1. Get the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, ReturnRecord>>` from the `.GroupBy()`
2. Use `.SelectMany()` to select all elements and save them into an IEnumerable
3. Now you can convert your IEnumerable into a List with `.List()`

**Example:**

```cs
// Longer Alternative
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, ReturnRecord>> groups = resultList
    .GroupBy((rec => rec.PropertyAddress);
IEnumerable<ReturnRecord> result = groups.SelectMany(group => group);
List<ReturnRecord> listResult = result.ToList();
return Ok(listResult);

// Shorter Alternative
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, ReturnRecord>> groups = resultList
    .GroupBy((rec => rec.PropertyAddress);
IEnumerable<ReturnRecord> result = groups.SelectMany(group => group);
return Ok(result.ToList());
```